# What are some healthy food to eat in between meals when a person gets hungry?

Tags: nutrition, diet, snacks-snacking-snack

For some reason, I get hungry pretty fast. This leads to unhealthy behaviour of eating snacks to keep the hunger away. What are some healthy food to eat in between meals to ward off hunger?

Comment: just drink beer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what your definition of `healthy` is really. If you're looking for something low calorie, I would suggest a large bowl of steamed vegetables. If you heavily season them avoiding salt if you can - think pepper and paprika, they are surprisingly delicious.

Just cook frozen vegetables like brocoli, corn or peas in a bowl. You can buy them from any supermarket for super cheap, and the meal takes 5 mins in the microwave with basically no prep.

10/10 healthy
10/10 easy

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. This answer might be on good track. But we prefer answers that are a bit more comprehensive (i.e. 'longer').  The rules here require supporting evidence for your answers. Please review the help docs to improve this answer and especially this meta post: https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/783/11231

Answer (score 1):

If you get hungry very fast, you are most likely not eating enough for your activity level or not getting the right nutrient ratios.  Typically, if you up the protein and fiber content in your meals/snacks you'll be less hungry in general.

If you feel you are eating enough, check on whether or not your hunger is "real".  Sometimes things like not drinking enough water, too little sleep, etc. can trick you into thinking you are hungry, or, you may just wanting something to snack on out of boredom.  If this is the case, good snacks may be food that are lower calorie but high in volume, like:

- Vegetables (and if you aren't a big fan, try adding some seasoning and roasting until crunchy)
- Apple slices, banana, berries
- Sunflower seeds (which take a while to eat shelled)
- Air popped popcorn

For more nutrient dense snacks when you are truly hungry, find foods with a higher healthy fat content (will keep you focused and full) and a higher protein content (keeps you fuller longer), like:

- 1oz of nuts (not strictly 1oz, but it is easy to overeat nuts)
- An egg or two on toast
- Banana or apple with peanut/nut butter and cinnamon
- Protein shake or bar
- Avocado on toast
- Veggies and hummus
- Grilled chicken

And if you find that you are lacking energy to get through the day or that exercise is abnormally draining, you may want to add more carbohydrates, like:

- Bakes potato/Sweet potato
- Rice and beans
- Sprouted grain toast
- English muffin

These are just some simple suggestions, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: While I see not much wrong with this answer, [sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references) might improve it a lot. In fact we require some backup here on Health.